# JSF Displaying OneToMany Entity

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I have two entities joined together and executing a named query. When I try to display them on my JSF page I can not see the data. However, in debug I can see the entities and the data is there.

JSF Page

```
<ui:repeat id="headerList" var="header" value="#{tModel.tHeader}">  
    <tr>
        <td>#{header.rbid}</td>
        <td>#{header.uploadTimestamp}</td>
        <td>
            <ui:repeat id="authList" var="auth" value="#{header.auth}">
                #{auth.username} 
            </ui:repeat>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

Model

```
public Collection<THeader> getTHeader() {
    return tHeader;
}

public void init() {
    tHeader = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("THeader.findByUsername").setParameter("username", userBeanRef.get().getUserName()).getResultList();
}
```

Header Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "theader")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="THeader.findByUsername",
        query="SELECT h, a FROM THeader h INNER JOIN h.auth a WHERE a.username = :username")
})

public class THeader {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5906810279679409035L;

@Column(name = "rbid")
private String rbid;

@JoinColumn(name = "header_id")
@OneToMany
private List<TAuth> auth;

@Column(name = "upload_timestamp")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date upload_timestamp;

public String getRbid() {
    return rbid;
}

public void setRbid(String rbid) {
    this.rbid = rbid;
}

public List<TAuth> getAuth() {
    return auth;
}

public void setAuth(List<TAuth> auth) {
    this.auth = auth;
}

public Date getUploadTimestamp() {
    return upload_timestamp;
}

public void setUploadTimestamp(Date upload_timestamp) {
    this.upload_timestamp = upload_timestamp;
}

}
```

Auth Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tauth")
public class TAuth {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5906752349589409035L;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "header_id")
private int header_id;

public int getHeader_id() {
    return header_id;
}

public void setHeader_id(int header_id) {
    this.header_id = header_id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the UI:Repeat I was using the var="header". Using a different name such as var="hdr" resolved the issue.